# What's the best way of managing Google Chrome for users with a mandatory profile?

Tags: google-chrome, profile

The users on our network all use mandatory profiles, and the settings of certain applications are hived to a remote filesystem when they log on or off.  Recently I've been attempting to make Google Chrome work this way and I've been struggling.

Firstly Chrome doesn't really use `AppData\Roaming` for its settings as it really should do.  Instead it uses `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome`.  I've attempted to mirror this folder onto the remote share when users log on/off (excluding the Cache and Media Cache folders) and this works well, except for one thing:  Bookmarks/history/extensions are all restored but Google's link to the cloud is lost.  It appears that Google must store some credential information which it uses when communicating with its cloud service.  However, no amount of procmon is showing me where this information is stored.  It's not stored in the form of Windows Credentials/Certificates and I can't see anywhere in the filesystem/registry where it's stored.

Has anyone got any experiencing of managing Chrome for the enterprise?

Comment: Did you try Chrome for business? http://www.google.it/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Google Chrome for Business http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/

This support document from Google, may help better guide you and answer any additional questions.

http://support.google.com/chromeos/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187948